# Lights turn on at different times?

Tags: electrical

Very confused.

I already had 2 rows of lights, as seen in the photo below.

Today, I added a 3rd of lights ... by pigtailing into the second rows junction box.

Now, when I flip the switch, the 3rd row turns on about a second before the first two rows turn on.

Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: Is this standard 120v light system, no controller etc, in the hookup?

Comment: LED’s. No controller. Just hardwired. Standard 120v. All 3 rows are the same LED’s. First 2 rows turn on 1 second after the 3rd row.

Comment: These are them: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01HBT3BVM/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_i_gGsJEbSAKJ1BZ

Comment: Is the light switch a regular flip light switch or a dimmer?

Answer (score 3):

Possible reasons are: 
1) All the rows are the same brand/Type but the first two rows purchased were purchased and installed sometime in the past, maybe a year.  The third row is the same brand, but was recently purchased.  The vendor made an improvement to the driver circuit and removed the delay.  The original two had the delay, but since they came on at the same time you did not notice until the newer lights were installed.  You could test this by disconnecting the third row and see if the first two rows still has the delay.

2) the third row is a different brand, with a better circuit design that eliminated the delay start.  In reality, this is the same as #1, with the third row of lights having the latest circuit design that eliminated the delay.

I purchased three sets of ceiling lights, same brand /model on sale, and the internal circuit, driver, and placement of the driver for the LEDs were different in all three sets.  Improvement in LED lighting is constantly evolving.

Comment: Like the test scenario above, try swapping the lights in 2 rows, if possible. This would show you if the new ones were  "upgraded" LEDs

Answer (score 1):

I have had this delay with LED lights before and I believe that it has something to do with the electronics. My guess is that the other lights are not LED or another brand. You can try another brand to see if you can get a smaller delay or just live with it.